# Why the command “grep” doesn’t work with no parameters?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface

I’ve been trying to use the command grep, but without the -R parameter the whole cli goes just idle.
Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Your question isn't really about programming but about how to use a particular application (grep). It is answered in [the grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs): "*If no input is specified, `grep` searches the working directory `.` if given a command-line option specifying recursion; otherwise, `grep` searches standard input.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're not providing any files at all to search. If that's the case, then `grep` is reading from stdin (standard input). It's waiting for you to close the input (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), and then it'll search that.

If you want to search files, you need to tell it what files to search. Perhaps you mean to include `*` in your command?

Comment: Ok i got it
Just one last question, when i'm in the "input state" (As soon as i send the command grep string), i can specify as many file as I want and dividing them by the space or the enter command; and then, when i'm done, i'll press Ctrl-D, am i right?

Comment: No. If you provide no files, then you're grepping the input itself, not files named in the input. If you want to name files to search, put them on the command line. See `man grep` for details.